# Android - Acra 5 dynamic uri

Tags: android, acra

I want to ask if there is any way to change the report `URI` dynamically. For instance, user change server and then I want to change Acra `URI`. I didn't find anything about it in Acra wiki nor any other sources. 
`ACRA.getConfig()` etc. are no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `ReportSenderFactory`. `HttpSender` has a constructor parameter which accepts an `URI`, which you can load e.g. from preferences.

Comment: And what should I do with Factory? Regarding to wiki I can use it in @AcraCore annotation. But I want to know how to use it to "reinit" acra when for instance user click button.

Comment: Just register the factory as described in the wiki. It will be called right before a sender is needed, so it can load the current uri e.g. from preferences. No need to reinit acra at all.

Comment: Thanks you for help